# SMS Reminder remain from Server Side in php

Tags: php, ajax

what is doing on SMS send Reminder to remain from Server Side for package end within 7 days or less than 10 days? any code or example video how to implement query.

I want the alert will come out about 2 weeks before the expiry date.

Comment: ask appropiate question here so the developers can help you

Answer (score 0):

Many Paid SMS api available in online.

Here i'm using [SmsHorizon](http://smshorizon.co.in/)

```
// Replace with your username
```

$user = "yourname";

```
// Replace with your API KEY (We have sent API KEY on activation email, also available on panel)
```

$apikey = "ABCBEFGH786756";

```
// Replace if you have your own Sender ID, else donot change
```

$senderid  =  "WEBSMS";

```
// For Plain Text, use "txt" ; for Unicode symbols or regional Languages like hindi/tamil/kannada use "uni"
```

$type   =  "txt";

```
// Database Configuration
```

$con = mysql_connect("143.114.0.49","username","password");
$con_db = mysql_select_db("db_name",$con);

```
/***********************Over Speed Alert***/ //Run every 1 minute

$i = 0; 
$message = "2 Week Before Expiry Alert.\n" ;
$device_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name);     // Write whatever the query you've required.
while($device_value = mysql_fetch_array($device_query))
{
    $message.= ""; // Content you load here.
    $i++;
}

// Replace with the destination mobile Number to which you want to send sms
$mobile = array('9999999999');

// Replace with your Message content
$message = urlencode($message);

if($i > 0)
{
    for($j = 0; $j < count($mobile); $j++)
    {   
    $ch = curl_init("http://smshorizon.co.in/api/sendsms.php?user=".$user."&apikey=".$apikey."&mobile=".$mobile[$j]."&senderid=".$senderid."&message=".$message."&type=".$type.""); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //$output = curl_exec($ch);     
    if(curl_errno($ch))
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);        
    // Display MSGID of the successful sms push
    //echo $output;
    }
}
```

Hope it help you.